# To call a component inside Dialog component in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 2 components called 
1) `demo` 
2) `add-customer`

In `demo` component i have an **button** called add. On clicking the button an function (ex **openDialog()** )is called to open an **dialog** window(i,e op-up window).Now i want to call `add-customer` component inside this **dialog** window.
 How can i do this. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-sovrog?file=app/demo/demo.component.html) link.

Comment: Hi,having trouble understanding your question. can you please reproduce your question,

Comment: From the add button  i am displaying the pop-up(i,e dialog), in that dialog i want to display the `add-customer` component.

Comment: I just want to display `add-customer` component inside the pop-up(i,e dialog window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo.component.ts you need to "insert" the component into the dialog.

```
import {AddCustomerComponent} from '../add-customer/add-customer.component'

 openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddCustomerComponent, {
      width: '450px',
    });
```

app.module.ts, add the component loaded in the dialog to the entryComponents

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DemoComponent,
    AddCustomerComponent,
    ],
entryComponents: [
    AddCustomerComponent
],
```

EDIT: to close on cancel you must add a click function to the cancel button on the add-customer.component.html

```
<button mat-raised-button type="button" class="Discard-btn" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Then on the .ts file add the function and also inject the dialogRef on the constructor

```
import {MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddCustomerComponent>) {}

    public cancel() {
       this.dialogRef.close();
    }
```

Comment: In the `add-customer` component there are 2 button called 1)`save` 2)`cancel`. On clicking `cancel` i want discard the pop-up.How can i do this?

Comment: In which .ts file in need write cance() function?

Comment: in the add-customer.component.ts, before any private methods.

Comment: Its working fine.Thank you so  much, you have saved my day.

Comment: glad I could help, have a nice day!

Comment: How do i pass data to the AddCustomerComponent

Comment: Is there a way, this could be achieved by using routes instead of referencing the component directly. Of course the route eventually resolve to the component referred. Using routes will save me a lot of rework because the caller need not worry if it is a dialog or a full screen component. it just routes may be with an additional parameter

Answer (score 2):

You have to first add the component you want to create dynamically as the entry component of the module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DemoComponent,
    AddCustomerComponent,
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [AddCustomerComponent] // This line
})
```

Then you have to use the method exposed by the angular material to add create the component you need as

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(AddCustomerComponent, {
  height: '400px',
  width: '600px',
});
```

This should work as expected.

You can see it workiing [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-fhwacv?file=app/demo/demo.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries. I have attached the working solution in the answer.

Comment: Is there a way, this could be achieved by using routes instead of referencing the component directly. Of course the route eventually resolve to the component referred. Using routes will save me a lot of rework because the caller need not worry if it is a dialog or a full screen component. it just routes may be with an additional parameter